# Are micro four thirds lenses fully interchangeable between brands?

Tags: lens, micro-four-thirds

I'm thinking about switching from DSLR to Micro 4/3, and I've found several brands of cameras and lenses, and I want to know if I buy a camera from a specific brand, will I be stuck to that brand lenses? Or I can mix different camera/lens brands?

**My main question is: Will the lenses be fully operational if I mix brands, or I won't have features like AF available?**

Comment: Not identical, but closely related: [Micro four thirds lens and camera compatibility](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27612/11924)

Comment: Also related [Are there drawbacks when using Panasonic lenses on Olympus Micro Four Thirds cameras?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/are-there-drawbacks-when-using-panasonic-lenses-on-olympus-micro-four-thirds-cam)

Comment: Just a footnote, but the flash communication protocol of the hotshoe is also identical across brands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can mix & match lenses from different manufacturers, with just a few caveats.

- Autofocus will work for all MFT lenses on all MFT bodies (that I am aware of).
- Image stabilization: Olympus does in-body image stabilization (IBIS), whereas Panasonic bodies prior the GX7 and GX8 placed the image stabilization in the lens.<sup>†</sup> This means that Olympus lenses on older Panasonic bodies will not have any image stabilization; conversely, some combinations of Olympus bodies with Panasonic lenses with hardware image stabilization switches will allow you to choose from either IS (either Olympus IBIS or Panasonic lens IS).
- Lens correction: in-camera lens correction is not guaranteed to work for all combinations. This is usually a low-impact issue: post-processing with software such as Lightroom can allow you to perform lens corrections.

---

†: User vclaw helpfully reminded me that the Panasonic Lumix GX7 and GX8 cameras have in-body image stabilization.

Comment: Note a few Panasonic cameras have in-body image stabilisation, eg the GX7 and GX8.

Comment: @vclaw thanks! I've updated the post to incorporate them.

Comment: @scottbb And GX85 :). Not a big deal though, unless you want to maintain answer with all the bodies that Panasonic is going to release :)

Comment: I use both Olympus and Panasonic lenses on Olympus bodies and switch off Panasonic lens image stabilization.  Results are great.

Answer (score -6):

There are many manufacturers of 4/3 cameras; some have interchangeable lenses with others, but not all. There are several different lens mounts. The designation 4/3 is about the sensor size.

Comment: Incorrect. The [Four Thirds System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Thirds_system) describes may aspects of the camera: sensor size (a 4/3"-type sensor); lens mount geometry (diameter, flange focal distance, bayonet design; and even lens design (image-space telecentric). Any manufacturer making a "Four Thirds System" camera or lens is building to the same specification. Interchangeability between manufacturers was one of the main goals driving the design of the spec, so smaller manufacturers could compete against the marketshare might of Canon and Nikon, by not competing with each other.