# Does Nocticron image stabilization works with non-Panasonic bodies?

Tags: image-stabilization, panasonic-lumix

I just got the Lumix Nocticron 42.5mm which has "optical image stabilization". Is this a purely lens-only stabilization that works independently of the body, or do I need a Panasonic body to take (full) advantage of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are micro four thirds lenses fully interchangeable between brands?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80385/are-micro-four-thirds-lenses-fully-interchangeable-between-brands)

Comment: @Itai I am asking about a particular lens and body combination. Also, I am asking particularly about OIS.

Comment: Olympus mirrorless cameras have in-body stabilization, so until recently they could not use OIS in lenses at all. There are only a handful of exceptions where the systems cooperate.

Comment: Newer Panasonic (as Olympus always had) cameras that also have a stabilizer in the body call this "dual image stabilization" (camera body + lens). Despite of that you have a switch on the ens to turn the OIS off (if you still have doubts).